# Best way to do TextView.setText() for lots of strings

Tags: android, string, printing, textview, settext

I have an app that needs to check a random number, and then print out from the string.xml file. Here is the code I currently have (it does carry on but it's just declaring the randNum and rand):

```
randNum = rand.nextInt(59);
 switch (randNum){
     case 1:
          random.setText(R.string.f_vocab1);
          break;
```

This (needs to) goes on for another 59 cases and strings. I've just started Android development so I don't have a clue for a better way to do this. Can someone please tell me a better way to do this?

Comment: Is your desired string "1" or "one"? If the former, you can use `random.setText("" + randNum);` without having to use a switch. If the latter, you will need to perform conversion.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a String Array in your strings.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="string_array_name">
        <item>first_string</item>
        <item>second_string</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In your code you can access this array with this line:

```
String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_name);
```

Now generate your random number and get the string by index:

```
int randNum = rand.nextInt(59);
random.setText(stringArray[randNum];
```

Note: To get a random number isn't what you want I think, because you will get negative values. You have to deal with this properly in your switch-block or with the array approach I'm suggesting.

Comment: I'd recommend this, this is what I was going to answer also